# How to identify whether or not a solid circle exists in an image using python?

Tags: python, image-recognition

I'm writing a code in Python that looks for solid circles in an image and outputs the number of circles, their diameter(s) and x & y coordinates of centers of each circle.

The challenge is that sometimes these circles may not be of uniform shape and may not be complete circles.

What is the easiest way to do this? I'm new to image processing in Python.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform

Answer (score 1):

Check out OpenCV for Python! Loads of great tools for doing exactly what you're looking for!

You can install most of the packages through your package installer or through PIP. Basically you just need numpy from what I remember, and a few libraries for specific image codecs.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

The docs page has some great tutorials which you could follow and adapt to whatever specifics you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) for editing/taking information from images. You will need to play around with that in order for it to be able to check if a circle exists, but here is a little example to open an image:

```
>>> import Image
>>> im = Image.open("myimage.jpg")
>>> im.show
```

An alternative is [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html), which is more oriented to photo detection and such.

For example, to check if a face is in an image with OpenCV, use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('face.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```